# Handle nameerrors when launching Dataflow jobs with Apache Beam notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I run [the example notebook Dataflow_Word_count.ipynb](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/interactive-pipeline-development#getting_started_with_notebooks) available on Google Cloud Platform's website, I can launch a Dataflow job using Apache Beam notebooks and the job completes successfully. The pipeline is define as follows.

```
class ReadWordsFromText(beam.PTransform):
    
    def __init__(self, file_pattern):
        self._file_pattern = file_pattern
    
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll.pipeline
                | beam.io.ReadFromText(self._file_pattern)
                | beam.FlatMap(lambda line: re.findall(r'[\w\']+', line.strip(), re.UNICODE)))
    
p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner())

words = p | 'read' >> ReadWordsFromText('gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt')

counts = (words 
          | 'count' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())

lower_counts = (words
                | "lower" >> beam.Map(lambda word: word.lower())
                | "lower_count" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement()
```

If I refactor the part that extract the words using a new function as follows

```
def extract_words(line):
    return re.findall(r'[\w\']+', line.strip(), re.UNICODE)

class ReadWordsFromText(beam.PTransform):
    
    def __init__(self, file_pattern):
        self._file_pattern = file_pattern
    
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll.pipeline
                | beam.io.ReadFromText(self._file_pattern)
                | beam.FlatMap(lambda line: extract_words(line)))
```

and run the notebook I get the following error message:

```
DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 570, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "<ipython-input-3-d48b3d7d5e4f>", line 12, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'extract_words' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 638, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 54, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 356, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 218, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 703, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 704, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1294, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 446, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 570, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "<ipython-input-3-d48b3d7d5e4f>", line 12, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'extract_words' is not defined [while running '[3]: read/FlatMap(<lambda at <ipython-input-3-d48b3d7d5e4f>:12>)']

Note: imports, functions and other variables defined in the global context of your __main__ file of your Dataflow pipeline are, by default, not available in the worker execution environment, and such references will cause a NameError, unless the --save_main_session pipeline option is set to True. Please see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#how-do-i-handle-nameerrors for additional documentation on configuring your worker execution environment.
```

To handle nameerrors I follow [the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#how-do-i-handle-nameerrors) and add the following line

```
options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session=True
```

but I get the following error when I run the notebook

```
DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 760, in run
    self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 501, in _load_main_session
    pickler.load_session(session_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 307, in load_session
    return dill.load_session(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 368, in load_session
    module = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'
```

Is there an easy way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using save_main_session, unpack the extract words outside  ReadWordsFromText composite transform.  Here is the example:

```
def extract_words(line):
    return re.findall(r'[\w\']+', line.strip(), re.UNICODE)

class ReadWordsFromText(beam.PTransform):
    
    def __init__(self, file_pattern):
        self._file_pattern = file_pattern
    
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll.pipeline
                | beam.io.ReadFromText(self._file_pattern)    
                )
    
words = (p | 'read' >> ReadWordsFromText('gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt')
           | 'Extract' >> beam.FlatMap(extract_words)
        )
counts = (words 
          | 'count' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround without modifying the pipeline is to put the function definition inside the DoFn definition as a class method.

```
class ReadWordsFromText(beam.PTransform):

  def extract_words(self, line):
    return re.findall(r'[\w\']+', line.strip(), re.UNICODE)

  def __init__(self, file_pattern):
    self._file_pattern = file_pattern

  def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (pcoll.pipeline
            | beam.io.ReadFromText(self._file_pattern)
            | beam.FlatMap(lambda line: self.extract_words(line)))
```