# No module named 'IPython' on GCP DataflowRunner with Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a fairly simple Apache Beam pipeline in Python I have set up in a Jupyter notebook and would like to deploy to a Dataflow runner.   I am fairy new to all 3 of these!  I am using the Python 3 and Apache Beam 2.27.0 kernel.

my pipeline options looks something like this:

```
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = 'inspired-studio-11111'
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = 'Dataflow Test Job2' + jobid
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).region = 'us-central1'
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = 'gs://bucket/staging'
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = 'gs://bucket/temp'
options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
```

The pipeline runs fine in the notebook and interacts with GCP storage.   When I set it up to run and run it on a GCP dataflow runner, I consistently get the following exception:

Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 771, in run self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 512, in _load_main_session pickler.load_session(session_file) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 318, in load_session return dill.load_session(file_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 368, in load_session module = unpickler.load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load obj = StockUnpickler.load(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'

Installing and importing ipython in my notebook did not help.  Does this need to be configured somewhere on the GCP VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is usually caused by using the save_main_session=True option.  See [Handle nameerrors when launching Dataflow jobs with Apache Beam notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202352/handle-nameerrors-when-launching-dataflow-jobs-with-apache-beam-notebooks) for a discussion on other ways of making sure the workers have the right code available at runtime.

Comment: that was the hint i needed.  i set options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = False and then in my case all the imports that the DoFns needed and all the classes they depended on just need to be imported/defined in the process() method itself.   The logs on GCP dataflow will tell you which ones are missing and where until they are all accounted for.  Makes sense if you think of it since the DoFns could be running as separate jobs.  Still not sure why save_main_session doesn't behave as expected but this alternate approach is fine.